# IntelliJ - Test coverage. Only show classes that is tested

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I run a Unit test with coverage, and get the Coverage list.
The list contains the class that I am testing, and also classes that I have not tested. See picture below.

Is it a way to automatically hide classes that is not tested?

[image]

Comment: why would you want that? Only having them show what you test kind of defeats the purpose. It is meant as an indication of how far you still have to go, and how much of your codebase remains untested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment of writing this answer (Intellij Idea 2019.3 and Bundled Coverage Plugin), there is no such option. 
Below are the only available configurations of Coverage Plugin.

[image]